# ruby list and store linux users in ruby array

Tags: ruby, list, system

I want to list and store linux users into ruby array?

I have tried using system command

```
system "Cat /etc/passwd |grep '/home' |cut -d: -f1"
```

but it only returns true

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the expected behavior. From [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system):

> system returns `true` if the command gives zero exit status, `false` for non zero exit status.

Use [`` Kernel#` ``](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-60) (backticks) instead:

```
output = `cat /etc/passwd |grep '/home' |cut -d: -f1`
```

[`String#lines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-lines) converts this into an array of lines.

Comment: Hi Stefan: Thanks this solves my problem. But I have heard that backticks doesn't allow dynamic variables right?. If I have to run dynamic command and get output from that command, then how do you suggest me to do that? Thanks

Comment: @Gagan it does, you can use string interpolation